# Midpoint sums Prob. 22" - I don't get the right answer because I don't understand what means "xxxxx.x" I think

Tags: java, math

I am trying to solve this exercise [Problem 22](http://www.cstutoringcenter.com/problems/problems.php?id=22) just for reinforcing my solving skills. I've already coded the answer. The task asks for "what is the sum of ALL the resulting y coordinates values? (Enter the number as a decimal in the form xxxxx.x (**I dont understand what this means**)) . My answers is 50616.0, but it is wrong.
 I hope you can help me. I don't know if I am doing wrong, or just I don't understand what the task means in the form xxxxx.x, I think it is decimal, no?

This is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Problema22 {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    File archivo = null;
    FileReader fr = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;


    try {
        archivo = new File("C:\\plane22.txt");
        fr = new FileReader(archivo);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String linea;
        int index = 0;
        int num = 0;
        String num2 = "";
        BigDecimal sol = BigDecimal.valueOf(0);

        while ((linea = br.readLine()) != null) //System.out.println(linea);
        {
            //System.out.println(linea);
            int line1 = linea.indexOf(",");
            int line2 = linea.lastIndexOf(",");
            int line3 = linea.indexOf("|");


            String y1 = linea.substring(line1+1, line3);
            String y2 = linea.substring(line2+1, linea.length() );

            long sumys = (Integer.parseInt(y1)+ Integer.parseInt(y2))/2;

            sol = BigDecimal.valueOf(sumys).add(sol);
            //System.out.println(sol);





        }

        System.out.println(sol);

        //count((ArrayList<String>) arr);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They want the result in the form "xxxxx.x", meaning 5 digits before the dot and one after. Your answer is incorrect because it is an integer, while they want a floating point number.

Comment: Using BigDecimal does not return a number with decimal??, I think that digdecimal does I will change all to float , thanks for answering

Comment: I change all to float and my answers is 50638.5, its correct thanks

Comment: @Yoan, `BigDecimal` _could_ work if you used it at every step of the way, but one of the intermediate values is stored in `long sumys`. If this were a `BigDecimal`, and the division were performed with `BigDecimal`, it ought to function perfectly. (Albeit probably slowly.)

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is introduced in this line:

```
long sumys = (Integer.parseInt(y1)+ Integer.parseInt(y2))/2;
```

The `/2` will truncate the `.5` if the sum of the two Y coordinates is odd. As it is for this line:

```
170,509|341,54
```

You compute `281` for this one, but the midpoint's Y coordinate is `281.5`.

I suggest parsing all the numbers into floating point variables and storing the intermediate results into floating point variables. A standard `double` should have the mantissa to accurately handle this data set.

Comment: I already do it I change all to float and I get correct answers,I thinks that BigDecimal will return a numbers with decimal, but no thanks